# how to call parametric method from inside the referesh $on function?

Tags: angularjs

I am having graph div. In that div i have given the referesh tool, and in the client controller I have to pass parametric function which will load data and then will remove the spinner

```
$scope.$on('panel-refresh', function(event, id) {
    spinnerId=id;
    // Instead of timeout you can request a chart data
    $scope.loadChart(streamStats, cloudStats);

});
```

and this the funtion

```
function loadChart(streamStats, cloudStats)
{

    streamStats.forEach(function (day)
    {
        var date = new Date(day._id);
        date.setHours(0, 0);
        streamSeries.push([date, day.count]);
    });

    cloudStats.forEach(function (day)
    {
        cloudSeries.push([new Date(day._id), day.count]);
    });

    $scope.splineData = [
        {
            "label": "Data Streams",
            "color": "#564aa3",
            "data": streamSeries
        },
        {
            "label": "Cloud Syncs",
            "color": "#2f80e7",
            "data": cloudSeries
        }
    ];
    vm.splineData = $scope.splineData;
    $scope.$broadcast('removeSpinner', spinnerId);
}
```

now problem is this that I am getting this error

```
angular.js:13236 ReferenceError: streamStats is not defined
at dashboard.controller.js:43
at Scope.$emit (angular.js:17070)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (panel-refresh.directive.js:42)
at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4732)
at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4544)
```

Comment: The error is quite clear, `streamStats` is undefined. Where do you define it?

Comment: in the funtion its ok. same funtion i am calling only. do i have to define it again